# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App' not found in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-snappy

I am try to use [laravel-snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) for pdf generation.

**step 1:**

run `composer require barryvdh/laravel-snappy`

**step 2:**

add in providers `Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,` and aliases `'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,` in app.php

**step 3:**

create function

```
    public function pdfTest() {
    $pdf = App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
    return $pdf->inline();
}
```

then found error:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App' not found
```

How to resolve it.I appreciate all response. Thanks Ahead.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add a backward slash before this line: `\App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');`

Or add `use App;` below your namespace.